# How to put a 1d string Array into a loop?

Tags: arrays, string, 2d

Im having problem with inputting name in my first,second,third,.. entry.. for example the output of my code will result in sth like this:

```
Ouput:
Input Name 1 : Input student hw score 1 : 2
Input student test score 1 : 3
Input finaltest score 1 : 2
```

So the problem is im unable to input any name in the loop so how can i fix this ?

```
public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Contoh : ");
        int noOfRows;
        int noOfColumns;
        int[][] noOfArrays;
        String names[];

        System.out.print("Input no of students : ");
        noOfRows  = sc.nextInt();
        noOfColumns = noOfRows;


       //////////////////////////////////
        names = new String[noOfRows];   

        ///////////////////////
        noOfArrays = new int[noOfRows][noOfColumns];

        System.out.println("====================");

        for(int i = 0 ; i<noOfRows ;i++)
        {
                System.out.print("Name "+(i+1)+" : ");
                names[i] = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Input students hw score "+(i+1)+" : ");
                noOfArrays[i][0] = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Input student test score "+(i+1)+" : ");
                noOfArrays[i][1] = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Input finaltest score "+(i+1)+" : ");
                noOfArrays[i][2] = sc.nextInt();
        }

    }
```

Comment: please express yourself more clearly. what is your goal and what you expect.

Comment: @marmeladze  the problem is im unable to input any string in the name array. so im expecting it to be something like this..
`Ouput:
Input Name 1 : Jimmy
Input student hw score 1 : 2
Input student test score 1 : 3
Input finaltest score 1 : 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `names[i] = sc.nextLine();` ----> `names[i] = sc.next();`

This will work.

Also,
your program will work only for number of students more than 3.

Answer (score 0):

I've no such deep java knowledge,  and this is my (may be not good) working example. Just add `sc.nextLine()` omitting eol.

```
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Contoh : ");
        int noOfRows;
        int noOfColumns;
        int[][] noOfArrays;


        System.out.print("Input no of students : ");
        noOfRows  = sc.nextInt();
        noOfColumns = noOfRows;


       //////////////////////////////////
        String names[] = new String[noOfRows];   
;
        ///////////////////////
        noOfArrays = new int[noOfRows][noOfColumns];

        System.out.println("====================");

        for(int i = 0 ; i<noOfRows ;i++)
        {       
                sc.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Name "+(i+1)+" :");
                names[i] = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Input students hw score "+(i+1)+" : ");
                noOfArrays[i][0] = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Input student test score "+(i+1)+" : ");
                noOfArrays[i][1] = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Input finaltest score "+(i+1)+" : ");
                noOfArrays[i][2] = sc.nextInt();

        }

    }
```